# Boost.MPI/Boost.Interprocess - how to detect if processes run on same machine?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, boost-interprocess, boost-mpi

So I use boost.mpi to run my app on 2 machine in a cluster, each has 8 cores.so I get 16 processes startedd. I wonder how my processes can find out on which of my clusters thay are ran? How thay somehow make names to machinesand save them?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `processor_name` method of the Boost.MPI environment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/environment.html#id473071-bb.  You can likely compare those (depending on your underlying MPI implementation) to know which ranks are on each host.